# Based on the last entered value the checkbox should be enabled in the dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create password validation in a dropdown.Based on the input field the check box will be enabled.If I enter an alphabet and number the conditions work fine.If I do vice versa, then the checkbox is not enabled.Basically,it skips the loop.I'm not sure whether this can be achieved by switch case as it should macth the regex pattern.Pfa my code.Thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
 width: 400px;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
     width: 430px;
}
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="password" id="Password" class="dropbtn">

  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content" >
<div class="row" style="text-align:left;"><input type="checkbox" id="strongPassword">8 - 16 characters long</div>
<div class="row" style="text-align:left;"><input type="checkbox" id="oneCharacter">At least one letter</div>
<div class="row" style="text-align:left;"><input type="checkbox" id="oneNumber">At least one number</div>
<div class="row" style="text-align:left;"><input type="checkbox" id="oneSymbol">At least one symbol</div>
<div class="row" style="text-align:left;"><input type="checkbox" id="">Doesn't contain invalid characters or spaces</div>
</div>


<script>

$("#Password").click(function() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
 
});
 $("#Password").keyup(function(){
            var InputValue = $(this).val();
      console.log(InputValue.length);
   if(InputValue.match(/^[a-zA-Z]$/)){
    $("#oneCharacter").attr('checked', true);
   }
   else if(InputValue.match(/^[0-9]*/)){
  
    $("#oneNumber").attr('checked', true);
   }
   else if(InputValue.length > 8 || InputValue.length < 16){  
    $("#strongPassword").attr('checked', true);
   }
        });
window.onclick = function(event) {

  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently running `if/else` but I assume you want to always check all conditions.

In that case always evaluate each condition every time and not in place of each other.

Also, for the length, if you want to make sure the password is between 8 - 16 characters don't `||` but `&&` the evaluation.

While I don't know regex well, the current ones seem to not check the input properly and for letters for example your regex only returned a match for the first characters.

My update seems to work but there might be better regex to use.

I have separated your evaluations into little methods for clarity but you can put them into your event handler if you like off course.

I also didn't fill in the missing validations as you didn't seem to ask for them but you can just update the 2 methods I provided and add the required regex evaluation or similar and it should work as the others.

```js
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}

$("#Password").click(function() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
});

$("#Password").keyup(function() {
  var input = $(this).val();
  
  $("#oneCharacter").attr('checked', hasLetters(input));
  $("#oneNumber").attr('checked', hasNumbers(input));
  $("#strongPassword").attr('checked', isStrong(input));
});

var isStrong = function(input){
    return input.length > 8 && input.length < 16
};

var hasLetters = function(input){
    return input.match(/[a-zA-Z]/);
};

var hasNumbers = function(input){
    return input.match(/[0-9]/);
};

var hasSymbols = function(input){
    return true;
};

var containsNoInvalidInput = function(input){
    return true;
};
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 400px;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  width: 430px;
}


}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="password" id="Password" class="dropbtn">

<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
  <div class="row" style="text-align:left;"><input type="checkbox" id="strongPassword">8 - 16 characters long</div>
  <div class="row" style="text-align:left;"><input type="checkbox" id="oneCharacter">At least one letter</div>
  <div class="row" style="text-align:left;"><input type="checkbox" id="oneNumber">At least one number</div>
  <div class="row" style="text-align:left;"><input type="checkbox" id="oneSymbol">At least one symbol</div>
  <div class="row" style="text-align:left;"><input type="checkbox" id="">Doesn't contain invalid characters or spaces</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's brilliant. For length,I tried something like this var isStrong = function(input){
    if(input.length > 8 && input.length < 16)
 return true;
}; and it works fine.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @HemaNandagopal Absolutely, feel free to replace any method and evaluations as needed :) I only separated them for clarity in the answer.